# Getting Linux working on ChromeOS Flex on older devices

Tags: grub, chrome-os

I installed ChromeOS Flex on my [late 2008 Macbook](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html). Unfortunately I cannot enable Linux mode yet. These threads on reddit ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/stl9fq/enabled_developer_mode_on_chromeos_flex_by/) and [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChromeOSFlex/comments/swxlz8/tutorial_enable_developer_mode_on_cros/)) that suggest changing ChromeOS Flex to developer mode would fix it.

So I added the `cros_debug` flag to `GRUB` (efi and syslinux) configuration files and I also checked for the `kvm-intel.vmentry_l1d_flush=always` flag and it was already present in every single grub config file entry.

Still when I try to start termina I get the following:

```
crosh> vmc start termina --untrusted
Error: operation `vm_start` failed: bad VM status: `VM_STATUS_FAILURE`: Host vulnerable against untrusted VM
[ERROR:src/main.rs:184] ERROR: command failed
```

Next I tried looking up the l1tf vulnerabilities on my laptop and this is what I encountered:

```
crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/l1tf
Mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: EPT disabled
```

Edit: I have now also added the `kvm-intel.ept=0` too, see bellow:

```
chronos@localhost / $ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/syslinux/vmlinuz.A init=/sbin/init boot=local rootwait ro noresume noswap loglevel=7 noinitrd console= kvm-intel.vmentry_l1d_flush=always kvm-intel.ept=0 dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 i915.modeset=1 cros_efi cros_debug root=/dev/dm-0 "dm=1 vroot none ro 1,0 4710400 verity payload=PARTUUID=E09BB354-34E7-5343-B0A2-BB06778C6B78 hashtree=PARTUUID=E09BB354-34E7-5343-B0A2-BB06778C6B78 hashstart=4710400 alg=sha256 root_hexdigest=<...> salt=<...>"
```

I am not sure what the mitigations mean in practical terms, but I wonder if are there any other `GRUB` flags I could add to overcome the error I am having starting crostini?

Comment: Using this as a source: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019230

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command in the shell of crosh to check the kernel vulnerabilities.

For example, there are still two vulnerabilities for `chromeOS Flex` 105.0.5195.4 dev on `iMac8,1`.

```
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name 
iMac8,1
```

```
$ grep -i Vulnerable /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds:Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/spec_store_bypass:Vulnerable
```

***I guess it can only use Linux when all vulnerabilities are mitigated or not affected.***

These two vulnerabilities on `iMac8,1` may need Intel microcode to fix them but Intel seems not to update the microcode for this CPU.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep microcode
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x60f, date = 2010-09-29
[    0.217648] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    0.802913] microcode: sig=0x10676, pf=0x80, revision=0x60f
[    0.802975] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
```